# too much HTML in an ajax script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I read from this [page](http://learn.jquery.com/performance/append-outside-loop/) that appending a lot of elements is bad practice and I should build up a string during each iteration of the loop and then set the HTML of the DOM element to that string. Does the same go for using too much HTML in the loop?

I have an AJAX script that parses JSON data. It requires adding data to different existing elements, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url",
    success: function (data) {

        $(data.query.results.json.json).each(function (index, item) {        
            var title = item.title,  // A,B,C or D
                age = item.age,
                background = item.background,
                ingredient = item.Ingredient; 
            $('.'+ title+'_ingredient').html(''+ingredient+'')
            $('.'+ title+'_age').html(''+age+'')
            $('.'+ title+'_background').html(''+background+'')
        });
    },
    error: function () {}
});
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="A_ingredient"></div>
  <div class="B_ingredient"></div>
  <div class="C_ingredient"></div>
  <div class="D_ingredient"></div>
  <div class="A_age"></div>
  <div class="B_age"></div>
  <div class="C_age"></div>
  <div class="D_age"></div>
  <div class="A_background"></div>
  <div class="B_background"></div>
  <div class="C_background"></div>
  <div class="D_background"></div>
```

Is it necessary to build up a string first? If so, can you show me how to do that?

Comment: if these elements have one parent node you can update parent html once instead updating elements html

Comment: When are you concatenating an empty string to a variable to another empty string?!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder , yes, that is my intention. I'm building a comparison table that allows people to compare a fixed set of items, so it's necessary to replace the old content with new iterations.

Comment: @user35295: You response implies there is only a single entry in the JSON data, otherwise you are only displaying the last one. Which is correct?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder @TrueBlueAussie . Ah, I realize what was wrong in the example. I've updated the example. I put `item.title` as the class selector to make sure every item is posted in different cells in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is purely about the time it takes to process calls to html() so they simply recommend you reduce the number of calls. In this case you could build them once in a loop then sets the div html once for each.

### Update:

Based on your update, aside from all the extra trailing quotes you don't need to add (a string is a string is a string), your code is fine as is. **You only hit each item once.**

e.g.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url",
    success: function (data) {

        $(data.query.results.json.json).each(function (index, item) {        
            var title = item.title,  // A,B,C or D
                age = item.age,
                background = item.background,
                ingredient = item.Ingredient; 
            $('.'+ title+'_ingredient').html(ingredient);
            $('.'+ title+'_age').html(age);
            $('.'+ title+'_background').html(background);
        });
    },
    error: function () {}
});
```

Note: If your item properties (`Age, Background, Ingredient`) are simple values (not objects or arrays), yo do not need the leading `''+`s either.

### Previous

Assuming you actually want to concatenate the results (you are only keeping the last ingredient at the moment), you could do something like this:

### e.g.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url",
    success: function (data) {
        var ingredients = '';
        $(data.query.results.json.json).each(function (index, item) {        
            var title = item.title;
            var ingredient = item.Ingredient; 
            ingredients += ingredient;
        });
        $('.aclass').html(ingredients);
        $('.bclass').html(ingredients);
        $('.cclass').html(ingredients);
        $('.dclass').html(ingredients);
    },
    error: function () {}
});
```

Which can be reduced to:

```
        $('.aclass,.bclass,.cclass,.dclass').html(ingredients);
```

The contents of each div are identical in your example, so you only need a single string.

In this instance you would probably need some form of delimiter between ingredients, but your example is too vague.

e.g.

```
 ingredients += ingredient + '<br/>';
```

Comment: I know what was wrong in the example. I've modified a little bit to use `item.title` as the class for each element.

Comment: Wish I'd keep my first lot of code now (one string per entry)... Will update :)

Comment: Sorry for the bad example. I should have given it more thought before posting it.

Comment: Seen a lot worse on SO :)

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you're setting the HTML on many different document elements.

If they're grouped in some way, for example all in a Div with ID #Container, you could build a string of the HTML and set the content of the whole Div at the end of it, something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url",
    success: function (data) {
    var sHTML="";
        $(data.query.results.json.json).each(function (index, item) {        
            var title = item.title,
                background = item.background,
                ingredient = item.Ingredient; 
            // not sure what your actual HTML is (div/span/td etc) but somethign like this?
            sHTML+="<div>"; // an opening container for this item
            sHTML+='<div class="'+title+'_ingredient">'+ingredient+'</div>')
            sHTML+='<div class="'+title+'_age">'+title+'</div>')
            sHTML+='<div class="'+title+'_background">'+background+'</div>')
            sHTML+="</div>";
        });
    $("#Container").html(sHTML);
    },
    error: function () {}
});
```

Note I haven't tested this code, but you see the principal hopefully.

That is, build a string of the HTML then set one element at the end with the content.
I have done this a lot in a recent project and haven't seen any speed issues (maybe 50 'items' to set in my case).

HTML will initially look like this :

```
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Then end up like this (2 x items in this example) :

```
<div id="container">
 <div>
  <div class="<sometitle1>_ingredient">ingredient 1</div>
  <div class="<sometitle1>_age">age 1</div>
  <div class="<sometitle1>_background">background 1</div>
 </div>
 <div>
  <div class="<sometitle2>_ingredient">ingredient 2</div>
  <div class="<sometitle2>_age">age 2</div>
  <div class="<sometitle2>_background">background 2</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

subsequent calls will replace the  element's content with new values, replacing the old items.

Building a string is, I would imagine, less processor-heavy than setting the html() on lots of elements individually. Each time you use html() I'm guessing that the browser has to go some way towards working out any knock-on effects like expanding the width of an element to accomodate it or whether events will still work as they did, etc - even if actual rendering is only run at the end of the process. This way you use html() once, although what you're setting is more complex.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I'm guessing that your suggestion only works if the elements don't exist, doesn't it? But in my case all the div elements actually exist and I'm trying to replace the old content with the new one.

Comment: Hiya, no worries - no it'll replace the content of the #Container DIV entirely, so will work if called repeatedly. The HTML will contain the new item elements, so when you do the .html() at the end, new elements of the same type / class etc but with different content will replace the old ones. I'll amed my answer to make that clearer